# Solving a matrix/vector equation

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, matrix-equations

Could anyone help me solve this equation for $c$:

$$a^T(B + sc^T) = \vec{0}.$$

Where
$a$ is an $i \times 1$ vector, $B$ is an $i \times v$ matrix, $s$ is an $i \times 1$ vector of $1$:s i.e.
$$s=\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\  \vdots \\  1 \end{bmatrix}$$
$c$ is an $v \times 1$ vector and the $0$ vector is $1 \times v$.

My initial approach was to do:

\begin{align*}
 a^TB + a^T(sc^T) &=  \vec{0} \\ a^T(sc^T) &= -a^TB
\end{align*}

but not sure where to go from there. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

By associativity of matrix multiplication, you can get
$$(a^\top s)c^\top = -a^\top B,$$
where $a^\top s$ is the scalar (well, $1 \times 1$ matrix) $a \cdot s$. Provided that $a$ and $s$ are not orthogonal, we can get
$$c^\top = \frac{-a^\top B}{a^\top s} \implies c = \frac{-B^\top a}{a^\top s}.$$
If $a$ and $s$ are orthogonal, then we can't solve for $c$; either $a^\top B = 0$, in which case any $c$ will work, or $a^\top B \neq 0$, in which case no $c$ will work.